# How to retrieve table name from database mapping class C# fluent nhibernate

Tags: c#, sql, fluent-nhibernate, system.reflection

I have itemMap class

```
 public class ItemMap : ClassMap<Item>
{
     public ItemMap()
    {
        Table("item");
        Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity().Column("id");
        Map(x => x.Inserted).Column("inserted").Not.Nullable()
    }
 }
```

What are the options of getting table name "item" from the code using C# reflection?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an extensionmethod for getting the tablename for a mapped class:

```
    public static string GetTableNameFromClass<T>(this ISession session)
    {
        var abstractEntityPersister = session.SessionFactory.GetClassMetadata(typeof(T)) as AbstractEntityPersister;

        return abstractEntityPersister?.TableName.Replace("[", "").Replace("]", "");
    }
```